# Read I/O (in this case the Serial Port) without blocking (Ruby)

Tags: ruby, io

I'm trying to read a serial port in Ruby using the serial port gem.  The problem is that sometimes there is not data to be read and when I  tell the program to read the serial port, the program hangs...  I've tried using `sp.read`, `sp.readline` and `sp.readlines`; they all cause the program to block (under Windows).

Does anybody know if there is a way that will not cause blocking?  Basically, I want that if there be no data to read, the

read result be nil.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [IO#read_nonblock](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/IO.html#method-i-read_nonblock):

```
begin
  result = io.read_nonblock(maxlen)
rescue IO::WaitReadable # this is raised when there's no data in the stream
  # don't wait and return nil
  result = nil
end
```

Comment: Thanks.  I'll look into that.  I thought I tried it and it didn't work but nuance made a mistake.  From memory, readline didn't block in Linux but blocked in Windeos which make no sense :(

Comment: Actually, your above answer doesn't actually work for me, but it does work if I remove IO::WaitReadable and just leave rescue to catch all exceptions.

Comment: catching `IO::EAGAINWaitReadable` instead should work